# disable chrome extension's badge

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension that shows notifications.
I am showing the notifications using these functions `chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor` and `chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText`.
This is what it looks like:

[image]

After the user have seen the notifications I want to remove this badge.

I have tried to make it transparent but this was the result:

[image]

Can anyone help me how to remove the badge, or if there is another way that makes what I want?

**Solution**

When writing an empty text, the badge goes away.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To remove the badge count, simply set the text as an empty string:

```
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
    'text': '' //an empty string displays nothing!
});
```

Comment: and how to remove the badge color ?!!
@ᔕᖺᘎᕊ

Comment: it goes away with an empty string

Comment: `chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({ 'text': numUnread || '' });`

Comment: @NathanMacInnes, do note that `setBadgeText` will throw if it is passed something other than a String for `'text'` (like an integer).

Answer (score 1):

Be aware if you set badge for especially tab to unset the text for this one:

```
chrome.tab.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs) {
    var tab = tabs[0];
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
        text: ''
        tabId: theTabId
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you stumble upon this (in 2022) use action instead of browserAction:

```
chrome.action.setBadgeText({text: ""});
```

as seen [in the API documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/action/#method-setBadgeText).

If you are also wondering where you should place the function call to trigger the badge text going away when opening the popup, just put in your popup.js (or however your content script is named).

If you want to trigger some extra logic in your background script when removing the badge text you could send a message from your popup.js via

```
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage("clearBadge", (response) => console.log("Badge 
    cleared"));
```

and in your backgroundworker.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if(message === "clearBadge"){
    chrome.action.setBadgeText({text: ""});
    //do something else
  }
});
```